# Libsodium decryption returns empty response

Tags: php, laravel, cryptography, libsodium

I can't get Libsodium to decrypt a response I'm receiving from a webhook but `openssl_decrypt` does. I'm not getting an error but I keep getting a blank result which mean I must be doing something wrong.

The reason I want to use Libsodium over OpenSSL is that it's more reliable. In high traffic scenarios, `openssl_decrypt` becomes quite unreliable.

Here's my code:

```
public function webhook(Request $request) {

    $psp = new Psp();
    $transaction_state = new \stdClass();
    $transaction_state->state = 'Live';

    $key_from_configuration = 'B46FAC78301751BCB489AC6D878877CA9AD8A71278DA777DD91B1AAB82135817';
    $iv_from_http_header = $request->header('x-initialization-vector');
    $auth_tag_from_http_header = $request->header('x-authentication-tag');
    $http_body = file_get_contents('php://input');

    $key = hex2bin($key_from_configuration);
    $iv = hex2bin($iv_from_http_header);
    $auth_tag = hex2bin($auth_tag_from_http_header);
    $cipher_text = hex2bin($http_body.$auth_tag_from_http_header);

    // This works when $cipher_text = hex2bin($http_body)
    $result = openssl_decrypt($cipher_text, 'aes-256-gcm', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $auth_tag);

    // This does not work. According to the webhook docs, $cipher_text has to equal hex2bin($http_body.$auth_tag_from_http_header);
    $result = sodium_crypto_aead_aes256gcm_decrypt($cipher_text, NULL, $iv, $key);

    Storage::put('json.txt', $result);
}
```

The docs for the webhook aren't that great and the example they have is pre PHP v7.1. Here's their example code...

```
<?php
/* Php 7.1 or later */
    $key_from_configuration = "000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f";
    $iv_from_http_header = "000000000000000000000000";
    $auth_tag_from_http_header = "CE573FB7A41AB78E743180DC83FF09BD";
    $http_body = "0A3471C72D9BE49A8520F79C66BBD9A12FF9";

    $key = hex2bin($key_from_configuration);
    $iv = hex2bin($iv_from_http_header);
    $auth_tag = hex2bin($auth_tag_from_http_header);
    $cipher_text = hex2bin($http_body);

    $result = openssl_decrypt($cipher_text, "aes-256-gcm", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv, $auth_tag);
    print($result);

/* Php prior to 7.1 */
    /* Please refer Using Libsodium in PHP Projects */
    $key_from_configuration = "000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f";
    $iv_from_http_header = "000000000000000000000000";
    $auth_tag_from_http_header = "CE573FB7A41AB78E743180DC83FF09BD";
    $http_body = "0A3471C72D9BE49A8520F79C66BBD9A12FF9";

    $key = hex2bin($key_from_configuration);
    $iv = hex2bin($iv_from_http_header);
    $cipher_text = hex2bin($http_body . $auth_tag_from_http_header);

    $result = \Sodium\crypto_aead_aes256gcm_decrypt($cipher_text, NULL, $iv, $key);
    print($result);
?>
```

**Edit: Real world responses**

```
Key: 282F8C1F40FD0BF4E9C130CB5E3CE6624B78E3AEB89FF4E4DFBF5F4360B1488B
IV: D71C4DE2ACEF0EEB40AEAA25
Auth Tag: CE27C16EA5A3D772DBB10A42C5DF99C9
Ciper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


Key: 282F8C1F40FD0BF4E9C130CB5E3CE6624B78E3AEB89FF4E4DFBF5F4360B1488B
IV: 8C7A8CA57FA6EC8B78EFB4AE
Auth Tag: E2A22DA77F0C508403816A802AE00CEF
Ciper: 179DB919FBD81E8B3436724479F81CE83B4E6CBE41BCF585FD56C89C9B292BD7B140AE2582B456ED3990FDF2C2D02D3E46028185AF0271C54E089807D6C95B05F6D824BF8BF4DAA4B9423BD5688F19DDC3D592F67908C7F9DE03112422318A1C8E83247ACF7FA6D36C96995D1FE6C95696857C5E1F1F4B13D508ADD58DC3C14C000C7E23AFC677D10901CD19A0DCCBC19C87F80660E1C986DE0A258578B5105B9952FB2A59015BE7D6DC84095529A21E67EEE8DA29E8C7920862C5F729616C2EF4F7949E9E6529E29C49D26054B3234DA7501C18E7818CF8AA5CA1335A02438F0090BE9D22B1C5576535E9B2DF58765EDD0FBA629A86B8B9E0D2074EA5A0D5F2275CCF9EDAABF77C2E1CE1B74FCAC4F70991CB32F4309DBD59157D199F65B6FA84410C305F4DBD21288BD23A3A0A925F24F387C4F7B1527D5D9CDEE2B52090614D779DD0C4ED64ADDB395BAA5468B35889A0881D217F430681EE749DE0ABF8FCFA203CACB636A8A193EA716D503F8E60AE510A47A91B9A246528A89B665F18321F29AA3B3F0CA1952890ED562351EB3B20F71169872C44DDE54B71B79526A392EDF5941F88B8878525F002E1CCCC18E002C4EE779942931BD0AE4192497532F48939F3F4531EF2DDBD0893C79D060010D3C4943F71515D0BCDDE9AA497ACF8453325EC831F2269E16830BEF96D2B791F7570AF0313D7C35B8B1D69F7E1A127E110101A32B1B5669F51A07957A0968C7DE3A7294EED68B0EB661AFBB2384173D404708414731C4AC08C47FF128FAAA0E89C33B8BE9082B97C7A205989915489FC186D6931CE5A48A3E666D23A4BB0C37A07456037BD2EB9924FA714D149933B828BF1F74A7A6EA22979FAF7CE6F03247ED931656EFCDB891A2C7D781759FA9176D34E1244B9133297D42E8E3E3BAA066B218D5431C9CEA593ABD79E821A75634D13E0EAA50A626695AD6BC8DCA94812D4A44B90584803D6822F7BAB3C806454F7A88D1ADCE4D31F28914EEADD0E05F82BCB5E75503EF79E05ED3B0550B5D57A632226E9312232C6D1BE4B42D9


Key: 282F8C1F40FD0BF4E9C130CB5E3CE6624B78E3AEB89FF4E4DFBF5F4360B1488B
IV: 34227A5F7EF770D06AFF5802
Auth Tag: 0378EEE7AD576220256882D6084A4EAA
Ciper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
```

Answer (score 0):

Your simplified example, using both OpenSSL and Libsodium, producing the same output:

```php
$key   = hex2bin("000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f");
$nonce = hex2bin("000000000000000000000000");
$tag   = hex2bin("CE573FB7A41AB78E743180DC83FF09BD");
$ciphertext = hex2bin("0A3471C72D9BE49A8520F79C66BBD9A12FF9");

$msg = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, "aes-256-gcm", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $nonce, $tag);
assert($msg === '{"type":"PAYMENT"}');

$msg = sodium_crypto_aead_aes256gcm_decrypt($ciphertext . $tag, NULL, $nonce, $key);
assert($msg === '{"type":"PAYMENT"}');
```

Update: with your real-world data:

```php
$key   = hex2bin("282F8C1F40FD0BF4E9C130CB5E3CE6624B78E3AEB89FF4E4DFBF5F4360B1488B");
$nonce = hex2bin("34227A5F7EF770D06AFF5802");
$tag   = hex2bin("0378EEE7AD576220256882D6084A4EAA");
$ciphertext = hex2bin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

$msg = sodium_crypto_aead_aes256gcm_decrypt($ciphertext . $tag, NULL, $nonce, $key);
var_dump($msg);
```

As a side note, you should use `sodium_hex2bin()` instead of `hex2bin()` when decoding sensitive data, and if you are using the PECL libsodium extension, `sodium_crypto_aead_aes256gcm_decrypt_detached()` lets you provide the ciphertext and the tag as distinct parameters instead of having to concatenate them.

Comment: Seriously? When using the data supplied to me via the webhook, Libsodium isn't working. My variable is always empty but with openssl_decrypt it populates. I can't seem to work out why that is.

Comment: Chances are that the problem is not in that function call, but somewhere else in your application. Print the arguments before the function calls to verify that they are exactly the same in both cases, and that their length matches the example.

Comment: I tried that too. They were exactly the same which is the confusing bit. If Libsodium isn't working then openssl should't be either but it is.

Comment: Mentioning an exact set of parameters to reproduce that issue can help.

Comment: Hi @Frank, I've added 3 real world examples. I can't seem to decrypt them.

Comment: Take the code above, and just replace the key, nonce, tag and ciphertext values with the data you added. The ciphertexts are properly decrypted, both with openssl and libsodium.

Comment: Hi @Frank, I've tried that but it doesn't work. All I end up with is an empty variable.

Comment: There has to be a problem with your installation, then. Check that you have a CPU that supports AES with sodium_crypto_aead_aes256gcm_is_available() and maybe install a more recent version of PHP or the libsodium extension from https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php

Comment: I've already ran sodium_crypto_aead_aes256gcm_is_available() and it returned true. Also, I'm running PHP 7.2 but haven't tried the Libsodium extension yet. Have you managed to decrypt any of the real-world examples I provided?

Comment: See the example with your real-world data above. It decrypts perfectly. https://3v4l.org/cNb6G

Comment: That is so bizarre. In my Laravel app it just doesn't seem to work but doesn't throw an error either.

Comment: There is either a problem in your installation, or a bug in your application, laravel or PHP. But your original question should have been answered at this point.